# Understanding clearly how LSTM solves for vanishing and exploding gradient

Tags: machine-learning, gradient-descent, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am about to start coding an LSTM using Keras/Theano.

As I understand it, using an LSTM (as opposed to a vanilla RNN) avoids vanishing and exploding gradients.

Could someone explain clearly (or provide their favorite link to a clear answer) that explains how LSTM, with its forget gate, memory cell input, and memory cell output gate prevent both the vanishing and exploding gradients.

Are there any other variants of RNNs that also avoids these issues?  Or is LSTM the only RNN-variant that does this?

Comment: You could check this answer on quora :                  https://www.quora.com/How-does-LSTM-help-prevent-the-vanishing-and-exploding-gradient-problem-in-a-recurrent-neural-network